# PHP SoapClient __getLastResponse - how to display only one param

Tags: php, soap-client

When I run

> echo $client->__getLastResponse();

result is:

```
0 123 simple error
```

but

> var_dump($client->__getLastResponse());

result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap:Header/><soap:Body><p1:FunctionResponse xmlns:p1="http://www.domain.com"><p1:TArrayFunctionResult><p1:Status>0</p1:Status><p1:ErrorCode>123</p1:ErrorCode><p1:ErrorMessage>simple error</p1:ErrorMessage></p1:TArrayFunctionResult></p1:CreateFunctionResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Just need display **ErrorMessage** param
"simple error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a ***very*** dirty hack, you could use a regular expression.

```
<?php

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap:Header/><soap:Body><p1:FunctionResponse xmlns:p1="http://www.domain.com"><p1:TArrayFunctionResult><p1:Status>0</p1:Status><p1:ErrorCode>123</p1:ErrorCode><p1:ErrorMessage>simple error</p1:ErrorMessage></p1:TArrayFunctionResult></p1:CreateFunctionResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
XML;

preg_match("/\<p1:ErrorMessage\>(.*)\<\/p1:ErrorMessage\>/", $xml, $arrMatches);

echo $arrMatches[1];
```

https://eval.in/199000